# Alternative to X-Sendfile on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have plans this summer to build an E-commerce app for digital downloads and I usually deploy on Heroku. However, Heroku doesn't support X-Sendfile.

So, what's the alternative?

I've been searching for gems and was thinking this might be a good replacement: https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3 -- but, I'm not sure it's being actively maintained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should keep your assets on a CDN like S3/Cloudfront.  Then just redirect requests to it as necessary.

I would also use paperclip to manage the file.  It could look something like ...

```
class AssetController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @asset = Asset.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to URI.encode @asset.file.url
  end

end

class Asset

  has_attached_file :file,
      :path => YOUR_PATH,
      :storage => :s3,
      :s3_credentials => S3_CONFIG,
      :bucket => BUCKET_NAME

end
```

That should get your started.  Hope this helps